# Why while loop works when I write " " in the condition

Tags: c, string, while-loop

Why the output of this code tends to infinity . The output is qwertyqwertyqwerty......

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(" ")
    {
        printf("qwerty");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `" "` is a pointer that is not NULL. Same as `while(1)`. What did you expect?

Comment: How many times did you expect it to loop? You're using a constant value, so it's either zero or infinite.

Comment: How this is a pointer , what is it's (" ") value ?

Comment: *Any* string literal will decay to a pointer to its location, which as said won't be `NULL`. The string's *content* isn't relevant.

Comment: If you want to see the value, use `printf("%p", " ")`

Comment: Study: what is a string literal?

Comment: Out of curiosity: In what language did you observe `" "` being evaluated to `false`?

Answer (score 4):

Even `while("")` would be an infinite loop. In C, all string literals are implicitly treated as pointers into to string constants. `""` would be a one-byte portion of data (the implicit `\0` terminator itself) somewhere in memory and if you evaluate it, you get the address of it.

The interpretation of `" "` and `""` depends of the language you are using. Especially because many languages (including JavaScript, Perl, PHP, Python) provide an implicit conversion in conditional clauses and many of them also treat `" "` and `""` differently. Other languages like C#, Java and Delphi don't provide the implicit conversation.

C (and therefore also C++) make a string literal of it which is considered as of type `const char*` (pointer to constant data). When evaluated in conditional clauses the expression is always true. Read more in: [*String literals - cppreference.com*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) and [while loop - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/while).

"Pro tip": For further experiments with expressions, consider `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: This also works while(main) , this also resulted to infinity

Comment: @Prince In addition to the comment below the other answer: If you use a function name in an expression without *calling* it (i.e. without the parentheses after it), the function's address it been taken as the value, and since existing functions have addresses different from [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), it's always treated as true.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal, such as `" "`, represents an array of characters (C 2018 6.4.5 6). This one contains a space and a null character.

When used in `while (" ")`, this array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element (C 2018 6.3.2.1 3). (This conversion occurs whenever an array is used in an expression except as the operand of `sizeof`, the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array.)

The `while` statement iterates until its controlling expression compares equal to 0 (C 2018 6.8.5.1 4).

A pointer compares equal to zero, effectively a null pointer, only if it is a null pointer (C 2018 6.5.9 6).

Since the pointer resulting from the string literal points to the initial space character, it is not a null pointer, and it never compares equal to zero. So the loop iterates forever.

Comment: This also works while(main) , this also resulted to infinity

Comment: @Prince: `main` is a function designator. Function designators are automatically converted to function pointers, so `main` becomes `&main`. Comparing a pointer to zero evaluates as true only if it is a null pointer. `&main` is not a null pointer.

Comment: @Wolf: The official version I cite is not available online except through payment (and is not linkable then), and I prefer not to link citations to the official version to unofficial drafts.

Comment: @Wolf: I prefer not to link citations to the official version to unofficial drafts. I stated that opinion previously and do not see why you request it again.